# Write capital special letters using pyautogui write function

Tags: python, special-characters, pyautogui

I want to print capital german special letters like Ä,Ü,Ö using pyautogui.write, but it only types the letters if theyre not capital, so ä,ü,ö, since I dont know how to tell it the shift state

I added the following code at line 235 to _pyautogui_win.py file to enable it to print the special characters

```
'ß': 0xDB, # VK_OEM_4
'ü': 0xBA, # VK_OEM_1
'ö': 0xC0, # VK_OEM_3
'ä': 0xDE, # VK_OEM_7
```

Im sorry if its an obvious solution and i missed it